# ctrl+s with SelectOneMenu component issue In firefox browser

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu, ctrl

Using PF 5.2

On <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> when focus on selectOneMenu then value is resetting to default value. This issue fixed as said BalusC with reference of below link.

[SelectOneMenu resets and fires change event on ALT press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384394/selectonemenu-resets-and-fires-change-event-on-alt-press/)

did changes like below.

```
c.ESCAPE:a.handleEscapeKey(d);break}}).on("keypress.ui-selectonemenu"
```

But if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> properly then it is working (keep press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> without leave, after press <kbd>S</kbd>), but do very fast like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then immediately remove <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Again old issue is simulating.

Could suggest anything for this?